# Using exception handling to get a correct file input

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm trying to use a try{} catch{} to get a correct file input from the user, however I don't know how to keep asking for input until I get a valid file.  I can't use an if statement, this is what I have so far.  The file is filled with integers, and it applies to another method.  I have FileReader to make sure the file exists, if it doesn't it should throw an exception.

```
public static int readFilename() {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
int average = 0;

try{

    System.out.print("Enter a filename: ");
    input = scan.next();
    FileReader read = new FileReader(input);
    average = AverageFile.average(input);

}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Incorrect file input");


}


return average;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public static int readFilename() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    int average = 0;
    boolean flag= true;
    while(flag)
    {
    try{

        System.out.print("Enter a filename: ");
        input = scan.next();
        FileReader read = new FileReader(input);
        average = AverageFile.average(input);
         flag= false;

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Incorrect file input");


    }

    }
    return average;
    }
```